# AVPlayer buffering video in background viewcontroller causes memory issues

Tags: ios, objective-c, avplayer

I am making a live tv streaming app that has a viewcontroller with an AVPlayer.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    self.playerViewController = [[AVPlayerViewController alloc] init];
    self.playerViewController.player = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:StreamURL]];
    [self addChildViewController:self.playerViewController];
    [self.view addSubview:self.playerViewController.view];
    [self.playerViewController.player play];
}
```

I also have a button that presents a new viewcontroller with additional information. When I present that new viewcontroller the `AVPlayer` continues playing the audio and that is what I want.

The problem is - when I present the new viewcontroller the `AVPlayer` plays the audio in the background but keeps buffering the video and when the viewcontroller gets dismissed the `AVPlayer` fast forwards the video so that it can sync with the audio. That fast forwarding causes a huge jump in memory usage and I get an out of memory warning. The longer the new viewcontroller is in the foreground the bigger the memory jump is when I dismiss it.

How can I stop `AVPlayer` from buffering the video ?

Answer (score 1):

I may be late a little, but in case someone still has issue with this i can suggest to decrease player buffer on entering background. I understand that this isn't a perfect answer, but still this will help.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(onApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification:)
                                             name:UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification
                                           object:nil];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(onApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification:)
                                             name:UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification
                                           object:nil];
```

and then

```
- (void)onApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification:(NSNotification *)notification {
    self.playerItem.preferredForwardBufferDuration = 1;
}
- (void)onApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification:(NSNotification *)notification {
    self.playerItem.preferredForwardBufferDuration = 0;
}
```

also don't forget to remove observers in dealloc

```
 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
```

Comment: That's pretty good work around. The main reason it buffers in background when AVPlayer plays a live content is to keep the buffer fresh. It seems by setting a certain amount of forward buffer, it stops keep flushing and fill the buffer.